# How to don't create column in hibernate include some property in entity class

Tags: database-design, entity, seam, entity-relationship, hibernate-annotations

I want to property in entity seam. But I dont want to create column in database. for example my entity is ;

```java
    @Entity
    public class Category extends Item implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1154500438874768209L;
        private List<Product> example;
    private List<Item> children;

    public void addChild(Item child) {
        if (children == null) {
            children = new ArrayList<Item>();
    }

    if (!children.contains(child)) {
        children.add(child);
    }
     }

     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     public List<Item> getChildren() {
            return children;
     }

     public void setChildren(List<Item> children) {
          this.children = children;
     }

     public void setExample(List<Product> example) {
       this.example = example;
     }

     public List<Product> getExample() {
       return example;
     }
   }
```

in this entity children list is mapping database but I dont want to map example list in database. Hown can i do?

thx .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to persist a property of a class in Seam (Hibernate), annotate that property, either on the property itself or on the getter with the @Transient annotation. i.e.

```
@Transient
 public List<Product> getExample() {
       return example;
     }
```

Comment: WHat if i need to pull something like count or sum beside the rest of object? will this work ?

Comment: I suggest you raise this as a different question, it'll be easier to answer that way.

Comment: may you suggest me some question in order to have a chance to took over it

Comment: I'd suggest you use the "Ask Question" button at the top-right of the page, and write your own question. That way you can give all the details and receive help that focuses on the area you're having trouble with.

Comment: Yes i would do the same thing but actually i'm afraid of that there is an existing question and will be marked duplicate

Comment: Then use the search. If you can't find a similar question (this one is not similar), just ask it and someone will point out a duplicate if one exists. Either way, you'll get your answer.